# { error: invalid input syntax for integer: "undefined", when trying to update backend column

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I am using postgresql db as well as expressJs with react. Currently I want to update a single column which is `inCart` inside my db, I have used a fetch function to use a `PUT` method and I call upon the function when `onClick` is triggered, but how can i change the value inside the db after `onClick` is triggered? Here is my current code that I am using.

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./ProductPageBody.scss";

const ProductPageBody = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  let { shirtName } = useParams();
  let shirt = products.filter(product => product.name === shirtName);

  const [inCart, setInCart] = useState(shirt.inCart);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/carts/");
      const jsonData = await response.json();

      setProducts(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  //Update inCart Function
  const updateInCart = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      {e => setInCart("true")};
      const body = { inCart };
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/carts/${shirt.id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      })
      console.log(response);

    } catch (err) 
    {
      console.error(err.message)  
    }
  } 

  return (
    <div
      className="container-fluid mt-5 m-auto p-0"
      style={{ paddingTop: "74px" }}
    >
      {shirt.map((shirt) => (
        <div className="row" key={shirt.id}>
          <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-4 ml-auto">
            <img
              src={shirt.image}
              alt={shirt.name}
              className="img-responsive w-100"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-3 h-25 mt-5 mr-auto">
            <h1>{shirt.name}</h1>
            <div className="Pricing mt-3 mb-5">
              <h3 className="text-danger float-left mr-4">
                ${shirt.price}
              </h3>
              <select className="buttons form-control float-left mb-2">
                <option>Small</option>
                <option>Medium</option>
                <option>Large</option>
              </select>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="buttons btn btn-danger mt-2 h-auto w-100"
                onClick={e => updateInCart(e)}
              >
                ADD TO CART
              </button>
            </div>

            <p>{shirt.description}</p>
            <ul className="mt-2">
              <li>{"95% polyester, 5% elastane (fabric composition may vary by 1%)"}</li>
              <li>{"95% polyester, 5% elastane (fabric composition may vary by 1%)"}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductPageBody;
```

I think i'm close but any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
Backend Express Code as requested:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const PORT = 5000;


//
//Middleware
//

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


//Listens for server to start
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Express Server has started on port", { PORT });
  });


//
//Routes
//

//Add a product
app.post("/carts", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.body;
    const { category } = req.body;
    const { price } = req.body;
    const { description } = req.body;
    const { image } = req.body;
    const newProduct = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO products(name, category, price, description, image) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *",
      [name, category, price, description, image]
    );
    res.json(newProduct.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

//Show all products
app.get("/carts", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allProducts = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM products");
    res.json(allProducts.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

//Show specific product
app.get("/carts/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $1", [
      id,
    ]);
    res.json(product.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

//Update a product
app.put("/carts/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { name } = req.body;
    const { category } = req.body;
    const { price } = req.body;
    const { description } = req.body;
    const { image } = req.body;
    const { in_cart } = req.body;
    const updateProduct = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE products SET name = $1, category = $2, price = $3, description = $4, image = $5, in_cart = $6 WHERE id = $7",
      [name, category, price, description, image, in_cart, id]
    );
    res.json("Successfuly Updated");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

//Delete a product
app.delete("/carts/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const deleteProduct = await pool.query(
      "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = $1",
      [id]
    );
    res.json("Successfuly Deleted");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you add your backend express code for the `http://localhost:5000/carts/${shirt.id}` API

Comment: @RohitAmbre Okay its added :)

Comment: your `PUT` api requires 6 parameters to update in DB and your sending `body` which contains `inCart` state which only has `true` in type string, so You need to send other product data as well

Comment: @RohitAmbre Is there anyway to just update a single column of data in a table? Also when i try to do console.log(shirts.name) it comes back as null so is it something to do with the let shirts = products.filter?

Comment: `shirts.name` can be coming `null` because your calling API and its result haven't set in your `products` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update single column at once, can be done in more than one ways, You can create a new API just to update single columns or you can modify your current API to handle updating columns based on values passed.

here's a small example API which can update any column from `Products` table, you'll need to pass data in following format.

URL = `http://localhost:5000/carts/${shirt.id}/single`

```
{
   "key" : "in_cart",
   "value" : true
}
```

```js
app.put("/carts/:id/single", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { key } = req.body;
    const { value } = req.body;
    
    const updateString = `${key} = ${value}`;  

    const updateProduct = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE products SET "+updateString+" WHERE id = $1",
      [id]
    );
    res.json("Successfully Updated");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```